Doubt in differentiation of trigonometric functions
According to a fundamental trigonometric limit identity attached below which was proved based on the sandwich theorem, I observe that in limit $\frac{\sin θ}θ, θ$ should be in radians unit and not in degrees unit. When $θ$ is in radians unit only, it will prove $\lim\limits_{\theta\to 0}\frac{\sin θ}θ = 1$ and not degrees.
My doubt is as in the proof of this limit is used in deriving differentiation of $\sin θ$ and a base for most of the trigonometric functions derivation, is there any restriction of evaluating the differentiation of trigonometric function to use only radian units for angles at certain places. If yes what are those and if not why?


Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

If you don't use radians, all these formulas are just false. See for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/a/507602.

Reiteration: use radians for trig functions in mathematics to avoid an endless stream of fiddly constants to memorize.
Length of a circular arc:\begin{align*}
\text{radians: }&  &  L &= r \theta  \\
\text{degrees: }&  &  L &= \frac{2 \pi r \theta}{360^\circ}
\end{align*}
Area of a sector of a circle:\begin{align*}
\text{radians: }&  &  A &= \frac{1}{2}\pi r^2 \theta  \\
\text{degrees: }&  &  A &= \frac{\pi r^2 \theta}{360^\circ}
\end{align*}
(And the "$1/2$" in the radians version is easier to remember when you learn calculus because the integral of $r\theta$ with respect to $r$ is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}r^2\theta$.  The "$1/2$"s in other places arise the same way: $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}mv^2$, for instance.)
However, the limit also works for radians, but you have to change everything to radians.  We change $\theta$, in radians, to $\phi$, in degrees, via $\theta = \frac{\pi}{180^\circ} \phi$ (introducing another constant to remember).
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\theta \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin \theta}{\theta}
    &= \lim_{\frac{\pi}{{180\;}^\circ} \phi \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin \frac{\pi}{180^\circ} \phi}{\frac{\pi}{180^\circ} \phi}  \\
    &= \lim_{\phi \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin \frac{\pi}{180^\circ} \phi}{\frac{\pi}{180^\circ} \phi}  \\
    &\overset{\text{L'H}}{=} \lim_{\phi \rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{180^\circ}\phi \right) \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\phi} \frac{\pi}{180^\circ}\phi }{\frac{\pi}{180^\circ} }  \\
    &= \lim_{\phi \rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos(0) \cdot \frac{\pi}{180^\circ} }{\frac{\pi}{180^\circ} }  \cdot \frac{\frac{180^\circ}{\pi}}{\frac{180^\circ}{\pi}}  \\
    &= \lim_{\phi \rightarrow 0} \frac{1 \cdot 1 }{1}  \\
    &= 1  \text{.}
\end{align*}
(Full Disclosure: I've used L'Hôpital's rule above.  For this particular limit, to avoid circular reasoning, the derivative of the sine function is found using the radian version of this limit.  If you prove only the degree version using the squeeze theorem, then the derivative of sine from this, the use of L'Hôpital's rule above is circular.)

It is crucial to exclusively use radians when working with calculus or other mathematical branches. To comprehend this, it's useful to understand what a degree is: A degree is not a real number; it simply represents the 1/360th part of a circle. Like a slice of pizza, a degree is essentially 1/360th part of the circle. When dealing with basic calculus and equations, we only employ radians, as they are a part of the real number system. For instance, 180 degrees is equivalent to π radians or 3.14 radians. Other measurement systems like Sexagesimal exist, but ultimately radians are the most commonly used in mathematics. Therefore, we should use radian measures exclusively for all purposes in Calculus. all purposes in Calculus.

When expressed in radians, an angle is the length of the arc (of that angle) in a circle where the radius is one. That means that it is not only a convention like degrees, but a true mathematical ratio. For that reason, the common trigonometric laws ($sin'=cos$, etc.) only make sense when angles are expressed in radians.
Said differently, you can use degrees in common life, for example when you speak of the angle of a roof. But in mathematics never ever try to use anything else than radians.
